# change document root on xampp 7.2.7 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apache2, xampp

I've installed xampp 7.2.7 and I'm trying to change the document root ,when I go to /opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf this is its content:

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Nothing about documentRoot,I this the wrong file to change configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been 8 months since you've asked this but for posterity reasons and because I couldn't find an answer elsewhere, the `DocumentRoot` tag that you're looking for is under `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`